# Select values based on several lines and columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have this table:

```
id       characteristic      value
 1          color            blue
 1          shape            rectangle
 2          color            green
 2          shape            triangle
```

I need to select the id's based on color and shape, for instance, I want to select the ids which the color is blue and the shape is rectangle (it would return only the value 1).

The primary key is composite (id + characteristic) so no id will have more than one value for a characteristic.

Also, there is the possibility to have more or less characteristics.

Could anyone help me on this one?

Best regards

Comment: Definitely a less than optimal table design... possible to rewrite the structure as this may be a nightmare for other queries as well.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting hung up? Are you getting any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: Ryan Kempt, unfortunately that's how it has to be...

Comment: digital.aaron: Maybe the most "obvious" thing, like "select id from table where ( characteristic = color and value = blue) and (  characteristic = shape and value = rectangle)". I'm just not getting any result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
  FROM  MyTable t
        JOIN MyTable t2 ON t.id = t2.id
 WHERE  t.characteristic  = 'color' AND t.value ='blue'
   AND  t2.characteristic = 'shape' AND t2.value='rectangle' --just fixed the t1 to t2
```

Comment: So, if I want to take 3 lines in consideration I needed to have a third representation of MyTable, like t3? and if I wanted to compare 50 lines it would be 50 "t's" (t50) right?

Comment: according to ur table design, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach where you don't need to change too much if the number of conditions changes:

```
with conditions as (
   select 'color' as characterstic, 'blue' as value from dual
   union all 
   select 'shape' as characterstic, 'rectangle' as value from dual
)
select id
from characteristics c2
where (characteristic, value) in ( select characteristic, value from conditions )
group by id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from conditions)
```

That way you just need to add another "row" in the CTE and don't need to change anything else.

Comment: I like your solution but I will also need to verify if the characteristic is not that value or contains the string, etc.. etc... So I guess I'll stay with Akhil! Thanks for your answer, though, I did not now about the "with xyz as"